# Why does my android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" not center my imagebutton?

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-relativelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:src="@drawable/play5evenlighter"
android:background="@null" 
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you have any idea why my android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" won't center the imagebutton? In the designer, the imagebutton is in the bottom left corner of the screen.

Thanks!

Comment: Your RelativeLayout has layout_width and layout_height set to wrap_content. Try setting those to match_parent. I'm pretty sure RelativeLayout doesn't have an orientation property either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for "layout_gravity":

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Ref: [android:layout_gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

> Standard gravity constant that a child supplies to its parent. Defines how the child view should be positioned, on both the X and Y axes, within its enclosing layout.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/RealTimeGraph"
        android:background="@null" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```